# Como puxar um especifico documento do firebase usando swift?

Tags: firebase, swift

Eu estou tentando pegar um documento dentro de uma coleção, mas só consigo pegar tudo de uma vez.

O caminho no firebase esta assim: Coleção: licoes-digital. Documentos: adulto(Esse é o que eu estou tentando pegar), infantil, juvenil.

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
    func loadLessons() -> Observable<[LessonsModel]> {
        let collection = self.db.collection("licoes-digital")
        return Observable.create { observer in
            collection.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error: \(err)")
                    observer.onError(err)
                } else {
                    var items : [LessonsModel] = []
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        var item = LessonsModel()
                        let data : [String:Any] = document.data()
                        let lessons : Array<[String:Any]> = data["licoes"] as! Array
                        for lesson in lessons {
                            item.cover = lesson["capa"] as! String
                            item.content = lesson["conteudo"] as! String
                            items.append(item)
                    }
                }
                observer.onNext(items)
            }

        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

Eu acho que o meu erro esta na linha :

```
collection.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
```

Eu deveria substituir getDocuments() pra pegar apenas um documento, mas eu não sei se existe uma função especifica pra isso, ou eu teria que criar. E se for necessário criar como criar ?

Answer (score 0):

creio que para obter apenas um documento a sua função a ser usada seria a `getDocument`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```swift
//substituir 'nome-do-doc' por: adulto,infantil,juvenil
let docRef = db.collection("licoes-digital").document("nome-do-doc") 

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        //transformar no seu objeto
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

Também recomendo evitar o force unwrap. Usar `nil coalescing` e `conditional binding` é mais seguro e não ocorrerá um crash caso algum valor não seja convertido com sucesso. Ficaria algo assim:

```
var item = LessonsModel()
let data : [String:Any] = document.data()
if let lessons = data["licoes"] as? Array<[String:Any]> {
  for lesson in lessons {
    item.cover = lesson["capa"] as? String ?? ""
    item.content = lesson["conteudo"] as? String ?? ""
    items.append(item)
  } 
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.